Trying to get Cron Jobs to run with joomla inCPanel
I'm trying to configure a valid call to cron
I'm using the following command in cron:
/usr/local/bin/ea-php81  /[root path]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php-s mysite.org -u username -p password -e Job -a execute
When I run this from a terminal window, I get the following error message:
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\UndefinedMethodError^ {#1813
#message: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "login" of class "Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication"."
#code: 0
#file: "./[path]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php"
#line: 481
trace: {
./[path]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php:481 {
CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->loadUser($username, $password = null)^
› //perform the login action
›   $instance->login($params);
›
}
./[path]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php:269 { …}
./[path]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php:67 { …}
./[path]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php:16 { …}
}
}
any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Version info:
pHp version 8.1. (the "/usr/local/bin/ea-php81" is from the web host's documentation)
Joomla version: 4.4.0
CiviCRM version: 5.67.1
Thanks!
--Phil

The background story here is that J4 further separated the Joomla CMS and the Joomla Framework. This changed a lot of things when it comes to CLI applications. I had a first look at the CiviCRM Joomla adapter and it seems that to make it work it has to change radically.

Welcome to SE.  If you can, I suggest using the cv cron method - might be easier than debugging what's happening there.

Loaded cv.phar.  took some fiddling to get the paths right, and had to change php.ini to allow_url_fopen to "true"...   once that was done Cron Jobs started executing as expected.
